# Upload csv file to mysql using php - success but no records

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload

I'm able to connect to the database and I'm able to successfully upload the data. But, when I go to browse the data using phpmyAdmin there are zero records. Any ideas what might be happening?

```
<?php

include "connect.php"; //Connect to Database

$deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE plfwinvtable"; //empty the table of its current records
mysql_query($deleterecords);

//Upload File
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
        echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
        readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into plfwinvtable(Barcode, Brand, Description, Category, Price, Size, Unit, ServeOz, NumDrinks, NameVar) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]')";

        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    fclose($handle);

    print "Import done";

    //view upload form
}else {

    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>";

    print "File name to import:<br />\n";

    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Please **don't** use the old and deprecated `mysql` extension. It's 2015 now. Switch to something like `mysqli` or `pdo`. You also **only** need to truncate the table when the form is indeed submitted.

Comment: are you referring to my use of the word or something in the script

Comment: I'm just pointing out that you still are using the old `mysql` extension which is deprecated in php 5.5 and that you don't need to truncate your table each time the script runs.

Comment: I remove the truncate statement from the script and I still am getting the same result

Comment: Im confused in your reference to your use of extension are you referring proper nomenclature or something in the script?

Comment: a) for a start, you could output `$import` after it is constructed, so you see whether there is any SQL executed. b) Please get yourself informed about the PHP-extensions mysqli and PDO_MYSQL (because the mysql extension will no longer be support by future versions of PHP), as well as prepared SQL statements and SQL injection (because of security risks in your code).